Sample Code: VB getNamedItem XML attribute in Microsoft MSXML.DOMDocument
Apologies, I know this is olden days stuff but I'm suffering a bit of brain fade here, I just need a specific code example to get on...
This is the problem using an XML snippet returnd by a remote service
<pap>
  <push-response push-id="99c2d0d3-6cce-4207-88c4-54bc8e852501">
    <address address-value="WIN">5557489580</address>
    <response-result code="1000"/>
  </push-response>
</pap>


I wrote a simple VB function years ago that extracts the data I want from the XML
<%@ Page Language="VB" explicit="true" validateRequest="false" %>
<%@ Import namespace="ADODB" %>
<%@ Import namespace="WinHttp" %>
<%@ Import namespace="MSXML" %>
<%@ Import namespace="Scripting" %>

<script language="VB" runat="Server">

Function ExtractDataFromXML2(ByRef sInputXML As String) As String
Dim XMLDom As MSXML.DOMDocument
Dim currNode As MSXML.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim Node As MSXML.IXMLDOMNode
Dim sError As String
Dim sMessageID As String
Dim sResult As String

XMLDom = New MSXML.DOMDocument
XMLDom.async = False
If (XMLDom.loadXML(sInputXML) = False) Then
    sResult = "XML Parse Error: " & XMLDom.parseError.reason & " code=" & XMLDom.parseError.errorCode & " " & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
Else
    currNode = XMLDom.selectNodes("//push-response")
    For Each Node In currNode
        sError = Node.selectSingleNode("response-result").attributes.getNamedItem("code").Text
        sMessageID = "rubbish"
        If sError = "1000" Then
            sResult = Node.selectSingleNode("address").Text & "@" & sMessageID
        Else
            sResult = "Error " & sError & ": " & Node.selectSingleNode("response-result").attributes.getNamedItem("desc").Text          
        End If
    Next Node
End If
ExtractDataFromXML2 = sResult
End Function

</script>

For the life of me, I can't remember how to get that GUID push-id into my sMessageID currently initialised "rubbish"
Works fine otherwise... just ONE LINE of VB required, please..?

This is not VBScript it’s VBA.

Right, in which case, it's VB.Net which is even more different.

Does this answer your question? Get Attributes XML in VB Net

Does this answer your question? How do I determine if an XmlNode has a specific attribute?

It just requires a little bit of searching before asking a question.

Sorted, Martin Honnen gave me the tip. Thanks for your interest, case closed.

You're missing the point but okay, you got your help good for you.

It should be.
sMessageID = Node.attributes.getNamedItem("push-id").Text


Cheers mate..! :o)

Where you answering for VBScript, VBA or VB.Net it's hard to tell. If it was VBScript there's already a very good canonical for it from over 7 years ago! - How to get XML attribute value?.

@user692942, I tried to suggest a statement following the syntax and methods and properties already used in the code and said to do the job for the other values, without being able to tell exactly which version/variant of VBX it is. I think the poster has later said it is VB.NET (although with MSXML?), I can't tell exactly. Let the poster decide whether the answer is helpful.

Either way, whether it's VBScript, VB.Net there's a canonical question that already exists if not multiple, all this does is dilute that still further with more ambiguity.
